# Using Azure Storage libraries in AzureML - Custom python library

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I am sort of new to Python, so I probably don't understand fully how to exactly import the libraries correctly into Azure ML.

I have a bunch of data stored in Table storage which I have local Python code to successfully join all of them as a preparation for the ML experiment. I learned that AzureML environment does not have the Azure-Storage libraries installed, and therefore procceded the steps according [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn955437.aspx) to upload a ZIP file containing the Azure-storage libraries that I found under anaconda3\lib\site-packages. I took all of the azure directories and shoved them under one single zip file and followed the bottom of the document in the link to upload the zip file as a DataSet and attach the dataset to an Execute Python script node in ML.

I am getting errors like this when I try to run the node:

```
requestId = 825883c7ccb74f7e869e68e60d3cd919 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. e "C:\pyhome\lib\ssl.py", line 856, in send return self._sslobj.write(data) File "C:\pyhome\lib\ssl.py", line 581, in write return self._sslobj.write(data)socket.timeout: The write operation timed outDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 376, in send timeout=timeout File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 609, in urlopen _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 247, in increment raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen body=body, headers=headers) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw) File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers) File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request self.endheaders(body) File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body) File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 911, in _send_output self.send(msg) File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 885, in send self.sock.sendall(data) File "C:\pyhome\lib\ssl.py", line 886, in sendall v = self.send(data[count:]) File "C:\pyhome\lib\ssl.py", line 856, in send return self._sslobj.write(data) File "C:\pyhome\lib\ssl.py", line 581, in write return self._sslobj.write(data)requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out',))During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 221, in _perform_request response = self._httpclient.perform_request(request) File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\_http\httpclient.py", line 114, in perform_request proxies=self.proxies) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 426, in send raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out',))During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs) File "C:\temp\fa22884a19884f658d411dc0bdf05715.py", line 33, in azureml_main data = table_service.query_entities(table_name) File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\table\tableservice.py", line 728, in query_entities resp = self._query_entities(*args, **kwargs) File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\table\tableservice.py", line 795, in _query_entities operation_context=_context) File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\table\tableservice.py", line 1093, in _perform_request return super(TableService, self)._perform_request(request, parser, parser_args, operation_context) File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 279, in _perform_request raise ex File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 251, in _perform_request raise AzureException(ex.args[0])azure.common.AzureException: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out',))Process returned with non-zero exit code
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure ML Studio, Python scripts (and R scripts for that matter) run in a sandbox so cannot access resources over the network. See [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/execute-python-scripts?#limitations):

> The Execute Python Script currently has the following limitations:
>
> 1. Sandboxed execution. The Python runtime is currently sandboxed and, as
>    a result, does not allow access to the network...

So if you want to read from a blob use the separate Import Data module and if you want to write to a blob use the separate Export Data module.